# Receiving data from SAP Web Application Server over HTTPS

Tags: php, http, idoc

I am trying to receive XML IDoc data from an SAP system. It should get push to me over HTTPS but something is not working. I gave out a SSL certificate and the IP address of the server. I can see that the SAP system is trying to send me something because I am getting a call from `Agent: SAP Web Application Server (1.0;701)` but no data is transmitted in GET, POST or FILE.

The SAP system is controlled by someone else. They got this working with some other server so I assume it must be my fault.

Currently my script logs these values:

```
serialize($_GET),
serialize($_POST),
serialize($_FILES), 
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 
$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 
serialize(apache_request_headers())
```

Header tells me:

```
content-type: text/xml
content-length: 76702
```

but I am not getting any content.

What I am doing wrong? How could I dig into this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution is to read HTTP body directly from `file_get_contents("php://input")`. The data has no variable so it's not getting parsed into any `$_POST` variable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ZSHPMNT05>...
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

Answer (score 1):

Thought the problem is not very clear but can you please let me know how are you connecting SAP 7.1 system with PHP.

> First of all, what need to do on the SAP side to expose a Remote
>   Function Module which can be accessed via RFC. All you need to do is
>   to create a ‘remote-enabled’ Function Module in SAP. This can be done
>   by ticking ‘Remote-enabled module’ under the function module’s
>   attributes.  You can write whatever program logic in ABAP in the Function Module.
>   Pay special attention to the Importing and Exporting parameters of the
>   Function Module as these will be what are passed to and from your PHP
>   program.

Comment: I am not connection to SAP at all. SAP should connet to me and send data over the Web Application Server. I am not sure how this works but I believe there is no RFC used at all because we are using a [push solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13073818/956397) not a pull.

Comment: Using SAP as web application server return's REST/SOAP response (did you try in this way?).

Comment: I can not change anything on the server but I found the data in the HTTP body. Thanks for you help!